# How does the statement a = a ^ b work in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax, swap

**in some languages...** I know this is serves as the exponential operator.
But in the following C++ code I believe this is being used to swap `char &a` and `char &b`. I'm looking to understand what is going on underneath the surface and how this statement works if does indeed do what I think it does.

```
void  swap ( char  & a ,  char  & b ) { 
a  =  a ^ b ; 
b  =  a ^ b ; 
a  =  a ^ b ; 
}
```

Comment: It's the XOR operator.

Comment: @Dai Could you elaborate a little on your answer? Please and thank you

Comment: @aSilveira: [Exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). By the way, this is not a good way to swap variables, just use `std::swap` from the standard library.

Comment: @Blastfurnace as I learn more about computer science, I really admire this sort of knowledge, could back up your claim please?

Comment: There are related questions/answers here on SO but I'll refer to [this Wikipedia page, specifically the "reasons for avoidance in practice"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know few things about XOR:

```
X^X=0
X^1= not X
X^0=X
X^Y=Y^X
```

Now

```
a=a^b
b=a^b=a^b^b=a
a=a^b=a^b^a=a^a^b=b
```

So as you stated and now can see, at the end `a` gets the balue of `b` and `b` gets the value of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with only one bit, take a look of all possible circumtances:

a 0 0 1 1

b 0 1 0 1

after the first statement:

a 0 1 1 0

b 0 1 0 1

second:

a 0 1 1 0

b 0 0 1 1

third:

a 0 1 0 1

b 0 0 1 1

Just apply the list above on every bit.